# Android: ImageView with TextView at the bottom

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to place an image with a label below the image, I have been trying a lot but couldn't prevent the image and text from overlapping,
Here is my layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"     >

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"/>


<TextView
        android:id="@+id/grid_item_label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:textSize="20dp">
</TextView>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this into your `TextView` `android:layout_below="@+id/grid_item_image"` and remove the `android:gravity="center"` from `TextView`

Comment: A: Hi, after doing the above things, my text view disappeared. btw, I am doing this 'gridView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(150, 150));' to the grid view in the code, is this anyway effecting the layout??

Comment: sure it affects, change your params to gridView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT));

Comment: But doing that is stretching my images too big, I want them to be 150X150

Comment: ok then just set only the width to 150, and height to wrap_content, otherwise it will clip the TextView

Answer (score 6):

You can simplify your layout by using the textview's compound drawable.

Remove your image view and set a drawableTop to your text view like this :

```
<TextView  
    android:id="@+id/grid_item_label"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    ...
    android:text="My Text" 
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/my_drawable"/>
```

You can also set a drawable in java code using the [setCompoundDrawable methods](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawables%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29)

More on this topic in this [blog post](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/815).

Comment: Thank you, But I am working on a grid view, so I would be having several images with lables, will the above fix apply in my case?

Comment: Sure! if the layout you posted is the cell layout it's perfect.